# Find files with matching directory and filename

Tags: java, io

I currently have to find files with these pattern and work on the, but I cannot find anything that would help me match the full directory + the filename of the file I need to explore

Here's an example of full directory that I need to work with.

```
/logs/xxx/production/jboss/instance*/xxx-production-zzzz*/xxx-production-zzzz*-XXX-Metrics.log
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you tried _anything_? Just asking for code doesn't work well on this site...

Comment: is this always going to be the file that you'd be accessing, then probably you can just do "String".contains("xxx-production-zzzz*-XXX-Metrics.log") and pull your file out. But as @BoristheSpider has mentioned. Try something and provide an error or piece of code so that it can corrected or refined.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I've tried to search multiple functions and logics to look for files that matches in directories that matches, but I could only find ways to look for files in preset directories.

Comment: Try a google search for "java find files wildcard", there are plenty of examples and options out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution found for this case. 
Had to import the ant.jar from apache.

```
                logs = new ArrayList<File>();               
                String basedir = "/logs/xxx/production/jboss";
                String[] include = {"pvmk*/xxx-production-zzzzz*/xxx-production-zzzzz*-XXX-Metrics.log"};
                System.out.println(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                System.out.println("Reading files...");
                DirectoryScanner scanner = new DirectoryScanner();
                scanner.setIncludes(include);
                scanner.setBasedir(basedir);
                scanner.setCaseSensitive( true );
                scanner.scan();
                String[] files = scanner.getIncludedFiles();
                for (String file : files) {
                    System.out.println("Loading file: " + file );
                    File log;
                    log = new File(new String ("/logs/xxx/production/jboss/" + file));
                    logs.add(log);
                }
```